# force QGIS-labels behind polygon areas

Tags: qgis, cartography, labeling

Is it possible to force labels behind a polygon dataset. In my case I want to put 50% transparent polygons onto areas, which are shown "inactive" on maps. Unfortunately, some feature labels are shown automatically above the "inactivity"-layer. Please have a look. [image]

Comment: what about removing those labels? http://www.digital-geography.com/labels-in-qgis-2-0-selective-labelling/#.VRWXDeER0fg

Comment: I think the goal is to still show the labels but have them screened by the semi-transparent layer as the other layers are. The same thing happens in ArcGIS - labels are generally always drawn on top of all layers. There are some exceptions and I don't know if QGIS has those same tools/settings, but one workaround commonly used is to create a semi-transparent *graphic* (for example in the layout) rather than actual layer. Another is to convert labels to an annotation layer.

Comment: @ChrisW , you're right. The labels should be shown, but under the transparent layer.