# Forcing label under point shapefile in QGIS 2.18?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I need to force the labels of the street names to be under the main point shapefile of a map. As I understood it, this is not possible, but perhaps somebody has a workaround. For now it would be enough if it could work in the print composer. Here is a sample situation:

[image]

The red diamonds are the main information of the map and the street names should also be seen, but if conflicting with the point shapefile they should be under those diamonds.

Comment: Similar question (but for polygons) : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140631/force-qgis-labels-behind-polygon-areas?rq=1. Alas, there's not answer over there. Another for lines : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103121/how-to-place-labels-under-a-vector-layer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the answer of @JGH and duplicated my layer to have the chance of adding further labels around the diamond. The only drawback for me is now that this diamond symbol will not highlight when I select the object, but I for now I can live with that.

Answer (score 4):

A workaround is to use the point symbol in the label itself. Luckily you are using a simple marker that can easily be reproduced in the label (vs categorized or proportional symbols)

So, create the label and use a transparent (and small) text. Then in the `background` tab, select svg and select `backgrounds/background_tilted_square.svg`. You can then set the symbol size and color.
At last, don't forget to put your point layer above the road layer and/or to play with the label priorities.

[image: Symbol in labels - text]

[image: Symbol in labels - svg]

Comment: Didn't think of that. But I actually have categorized markers (on the pic is only one category). And I am also planning to use labels for this shapefile as well, which is why this solution sadly is not a possibility for my case