# How to place symbols ON TOP of labels

Tags: qgis-3, labeling

Reviving an old question: How to place symbols **above** labels

- 3 years ago: [Forcing label under point shapefile in QGIS 2.18?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/257086/forcing-label-under-point-shapefile-in-qgis-2-18)
- 4 years ago: [Symbols above labels in map QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230671/symbols-above-labels-in-map-qgis)
- 7 years ago: [How to place labels under a vector layer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/103121/how-to-place-labels-under-a-vector-layer))

Is there a built in way to do this is QGIS 3? I'm looking for a way to do it that isn't a clunky double map display or doesn't force me to leave QGIS and use a drawing program.

In the previous iterations of this question there were several questions asking why one might want to do this. The image below shows that my labels are in text bubbles and I want to put the points on the edge (eg Hlɢ̲aagilda) or on top (eg K'il Kun) of the bubble.

[image]

Comment: Don't understand if you want to move the labels or put them behind the objects. Labels are always drawn on top of symbols. But you can move them with the label toolbar. Or you can use the rendering properties of the background or the buffer to be able to "see behind them": https://i.stack.imgur.com/w4TtV.png

Comment: One solution would be to create your symbol not as a symbology but as label (with no text and a symbol background) then you can order your label with the label z order option. For this to work you will need to check the show all label / allow superposition so it may create other labelling issues.....